# How to set multiple cross fields validators in a fromGroup Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-validation, angular-validator

I have a reactive form  that has very interrelated validations. I created a class that have all the functions for cross field validation, but if I try to set it using Validators.validator it does not trigger the functions. If I just used `{validator: MyValidatorClass.myCrossFieldValidator1}` this will work on that function, but I have more validators that I need to apply and its not good solution starting creating sub form Groups.

My code looks like this code but with other names

```
class MyValidatorClass {
  static myCrossFieldValidator1 ...
  static myCrossFieldValidator2 ...
  static myCrossFieldValidator2 ...
}
```

and the form:

```
 this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      field1: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.min(0), Validators.maxLength(2)]],  // Done
      field2: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.min(0)]],
      field3: ['', [Validators.required]],
      ...},
     { validator: MyValidatorClass .myCrossFieldValidator1 } // This works but only for one function myCrossFieldValidator1 and is not what I need
     // I have tried with 
     validators & Validators: [MyValidatorClass .myCrossFieldValidator1 
                              ,MyValidatorClass .myCrossFieldValidator12
                              ,MyValidatorClass .myCrossFieldValidator3]
```

// But this does not work 
    );

Other solutions around here recommend to declare sub groups or apply the function to a fields but what I am looking is to apply multiple custom cross field validators to my group. Not sure what is wrong or if is a limitation of the technology. Angular in its example only shows the easy case of one validator function https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#cross-field-validation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> validator: can be a single validator function, or an array of validator
>   functions

```
     this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({...},
         { validator: [ MyValidatorClass.myCrossFieldValidator1 , 
                        MyValidatorClass.myCrossFieldValidator12 ,
                        MyValidatorClass.myCrossFieldValidator3
                      ] 
});
```

[FormBuilder#group](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder#group)

Comment: Yes, indeed by the documentation but it does not work for me in real life. I tried as I explained in the question and the functions never get trigger

Comment: When you add the validators on group the work on the value of the group this mean fom it self  , can you share few validators so we can test them

Comment: Actually this works. Thank you looks that my error was that I was adding the s as plural but as soon as remove the s it works with the array as the doc and you pointed

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Validators.compose` like this:

```
{ validator: Validators.compose([
          MyValidatorClass.myCrossFieldValidator1, 
          MyValidatorClass.myCrossFieldValidator2
])}
```